# Angular 9 to Angular 11 Initialize observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

In the order to create an Observable in Angular 9, i must just write this :

```
export class CreateEntityComponent implements OnInit {

uploadPercent: Observable<number>;

constructor() {  }

}
```

How i can change my code ? Thanks

But in Angular 11 i have this error in ititialization :

> ```
> Property 'uploadPercent' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
> ```

Comment: How does `uploadPercent` get created in your code?

Comment: How i can create it ? i just ask it in my function uploadFile(){   this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();}

Comment: If you are using VS Code, when you click on the `uploadPercent` you should see a quick fix icon. Click on that icon and it gives you several choices for automatically fixing the issue. One of the options will most likely be to `Add definite assignment assertion to property` (which is the solution @digitalclover provided below).

Comment: You could do `uploadPercent?: Observable<number>`, but this does require you to handle cases where `uploadPercent` may be null. You could also initialize it to a value like `uploadPercent = of(0)`, but that also has implications if you are reassigning it since you want to make sure to unsubscribe any subscriptions to any of the Observables that get created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uploadPercent` is still `null` because you've only declared the type. If you are defining it elsewhere in the component you can use `uploadPercent!: Observable<number>;`